# Parse SharePoint Restful API Array Response C#

Tags: c#, json, sharepoint, json.net

I am trying to parse a JSON response from a SharePoint list and parse certain nodes to a list. There can be multiple records. I am using Newsoft Json to deserialize the response. Everything works expect the foreach loop I created iterates through the results one time. Also in the foreach loop the items variable has data as the results variable.

Here is the code:

```
  static List<string> get_json_unsubscribe()
  {
        int counter = 0;
        List<string> list_of_json_users = new List<string>();
        String url = "http://server/site/_api/lists/getbytitle('listname')" 
        HttpWebRequest endpointRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        endpointRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        endpointRequest.Method = "GET";
        endpointRequest.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
        HttpWebResponse endpointResponse = (HttpWebResponse)endpointRequest.GetResponse();

        Stream receiveStream = endpointResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);


        dynamic results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(readStream.ReadToEnd());
        foreach (var item in results)
        {
            string userid= results.d.results[counter].userid
            list_of_json_users.Add(userid);
            counter++;
        }

        return list_of_json_users;

    }
```

Comment: Wht's the point of "foreach (var item in results)" you never use item?

Comment: So has it successfully deserialized to IEnumerable object? Maybe try to use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>> instead of just dynamic

Comment: Trey, that is a good point and I will need to revisit it. Do you have any input on how I may loop through the results? I can't seem to find a count method that would tell me how many records there is.

Comment: @Senebt1ka  I get this error message when I add the list method To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Comment: What does the JSON look like?

Answer (score 4):

The endpoint:

```
http://server/site/_api/lists/getbytitle('<listtitle>')
```

returns *`List` resource properties*, you probably want this endpoint:

```
http://server/site/_api/lists/getbytitle('<listtitle>')/items
```

to return **list data** (`ListItemCollection` resource)

To deserialize your JSON you could introduce a model:

```
public class UserInfo
{
    [JsonProperty("AuthorId")]
    public string AuthorId { get; set; }

}


public class UserInfoResult
{
    [JsonProperty("results")]
    public List<UserInfo> UserInfoCollection { get; set; }
}


public class UserInfoResultRoot
{
    [JsonProperty("d")]
    public UserInfoResult Result { get; set; }
}
```

> Note: in the provided example `AuthorId` property of `ListItem`
>   resource is marked for deserialization

In that case deserializing of list items:

```
dynamic results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(readStream.ReadToEnd());
foreach (var item in results)
{
     string userid= results.d.results[counter].userid
     list_of_json_users.Add(userid);
     counter++;
}
```

could be replaced with:

```
var json = readStream.ReadToEnd();
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserInfoResultRoot>(json);
```

`list_of_json_users`could be initialized like this:

```
list_of_json_users = data.Result.UserInfoCollection.Select(ui => ui.AuthorId).ToList();
```